# Detect/Prevent unicode (alt + numpad) characters in inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to prevent input of `alt + numpad` unicode characters.

The alt key doesn't seem to register on keyup and will enter the unicode character regardless. (try something like 'alt + 1' in the example code snippet below to see what I mean.)

I've tried something like the following that attempts to restrict non-numeric characters:

```js
$("#myInput").on('paste keyup keydown change', function(event) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var value = $input.val();
    // remove whitespace
    value = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    // remove unwanted characters
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    $input.val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
```

Is there an event I should be looking for instead of the above 4? (`paste keyup keydown change`)

Comment: Typically you'd just run validation against an `input` rather than outright deleting anything that's not valid...

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes, Arguably this is a minor thing (as pressing any other key will immediately be detected and run the regex) however I was hoping for something more immediate. further more, I'm surprised this isn't detected by the events, wouldn't a keyup for alt key trigger it?

Comment: Not sure about how 'keypresses' are handled in that regard, but you could always add conditional logic to check what `.keyCode` is being entered.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent them on the keypress event...

```
function noteKeyPress(event) {
    if(event.code.slice(0,3) == 'Alt'){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

This page was a great [help](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys-cancel2.html?)